# Factorization into prime ideals in dedekind domain $\mathbb{C}[t]_{(t)}[x]/(x^3+x^2+t)$

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals, dedekind-domain

$R = \mathbb{C}[t]_{(t)}[x]/(x^3+x^2+t)$ is a dedekind domain. Therefore every proper ideal $I$ can be written as a product of prime ideals.

I want to find the factorization of $I = (t+x^2-x)$ into prime ideals in $R$.
I tried to describe the prime ideals of $S = \mathbb{C}[t]_{(t)}[x]$ the following way:

- zero ideal $(0)$
- $(f)$ where $f$ irreducible in $S$
- $(p)$ where $p$ prime in $\mathbb{C}[t]_{(t)}$
- $(p,f)$ where $p$ prime in $\mathbb{C}[t]_{(t)}$ and $f$ irreducible mod $p$

Then, the prime ideals in $R$ would correspond to those of $S$ that contain $(x^3+x^2+t)$.

Am I going in the right direction with this?
Also I'm not able to find the factorization, how do I have to do this?

Comment: Have you noticed that your ring is isomorphic to a ring of fractions of $\mathbb C[x]$ by $t\mapsto -x^2-x^3$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are on the right track. In fact, $I$ is a prime ideal.

In $R$, one sees that
$$
t + x^2 -x = (-x^3-x^2) + x^2 - x= -x^3-x = -x(x-i)(x+i). 
$$
Thus any prime ideal of $P$ containing $I$ must contain one of the ideals $(t,x)R, (t -1 -i,x-i)R$, or $(t-1+i,x+i)R$. 
Notice that the second and third cases cannot happen as $t-1-i, t-1+i$ are units in $R$. 
Therefore, since $R$ is a Dedekind domain, $I = P^a$ for some $a$, where $P = (t, x)$ (it is straightforward to check $P$ is prime).

One can determine $a$ locally. In $R_P$, $x$ is a uniformizing parameter, and the images of $x-i,x+i$ will be units. Thus
$IR_P = xR_P$. Hence $I = P$.

Of course, we could've checked that $R/I$ is a field directly, but I believe this approach is more general.